# How to click on a UI button even android native keyboard is visible on screen in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm setting up a login page, it have one TMP input field and one button(Login)  (both are placed top of the screen). When clicking on that input field it opens android native keyboard, after user entered their info on that field they are clicking on login button and waiting for response. Here what happens is after they entered their detail they are clicking outside the android native keyboard and on the login button(this both are single click not two different click) it close the android native keyboard but it won't trigger the login button. But users doesn't know that, so please help me with this.

### What I need is:

If android native keyboard opened and user clicked on login button it need to work first time itself. Thank you.

Below code is one which i tried, but it's not working if keyboard is opened.

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        PointerEventData pointerData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);

        pointerData.position = Input.mousePosition;

        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
        EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointerData, results);

        if (results.Count > 0)
        {
            //WorldUI is my layer name
            if (results[0].gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("UI"))
            {
                string dbg = "Root Element: {0} \n GrandChild Element: {1}";
                Debug.Log(string.Format(dbg, results[results.Count - 1].gameObject.name, results[0].gameObject.name));
                Debug.Log("Root Element: "+results[results.Count-1].gameObject.name);
                objectName.text = results[results.Count - 1].gameObject.name.ToString();
                //Debug.Log("GrandChild Element: "+results[0].gameObject.name);
                results.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `but it won't trigger the login button` well I guess that's how it works ... maybe you could somehow check the touch position in [`MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html) which afaik is called once the keyboard closes. Simply add a hint or something to tell the user that the button wasn't clicked so far. E.g. only enable the button if you are re-gaining focus on the app and the input field is not empty - Disable the button before and otherwise

Comment: Thank you for your comment @derHugo, I'll try onapplicationfocus to get touch position when it becomes true or I have to disable the button if keyboard isvisible true. Thank you.